# Why i have a NullPointerException when i set Calendar.getInstance() in a attribute of model?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, calendar, datetime-format

In my model i have this:

```
@Entity
public class Plan {
  ...
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private Calendar creationDate;
  ...
```

In eclipse debugger, i have a NullPointerException in this line:

```
plan.setCreationDate(instance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `plan` object isn't instantiated...

This will prevent the exception:

```
if (plan != null){
    plan.setCreationDate(instance);
}
```

Comment: OMG! This is a funny... You're right. After 1 year programming, I make mistakes like that make me feel ashamed. kk I'll sleep! Thx bro!

Comment: @ThiagoBASalles no problem ;)